# How do I use pandas melt to flatten out stacked columns into variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

Reading a matrix data with stacked columns in pandas

Hello ,

Newbie to Python here. Need some help in reading xls file with following format as pandas dataframe and writing it as a record

xls layout looks like this

[image: InputIMage]

```
    |   SP500 | DJIA    
    |   Equity| Equity
    |   Large | BlueChip
-----------------------------           
1-Apr-23 |  3.51  | 2.56
1-Mar-23 |  -2.61 | 1.89
1-Feb-23 |  6.18  | -4.06
1-Jan-23 |  -5.9  | 2.83
```

Basically its a timeseries of performance return of 2 major indices.

I'd like to flatten it out something like this

[image: OutputDataFrameImage]

```
Date     | Index | AssetClass | Type     | Return
1-Apr-23 | SP500 | Equities   | Large    | 3.51
1-Mar-23 | SP500 | Equities   | Large    | -2.61
1-Feb-23 | SP500 | Equities   | Large    | 6.18
1-Jan-23 | SP500 | Equities   | Large    | -5.9
1-Apr-23 | DJIA  | Equities   | BlueChip | 2.56
1-Mar-23 | DJIA  | Equities   | BlueChip | 1.89
1-Feb-23 | DJIA  | Equities   | BlueChip | -4.06
1-Jan-23 | DJIA  | Equities   | BlueChip | 2.83
```

For a single column header, I used `dataframe.melt()` function to flatten it out. I am unsure how I could achieve it for stacked columns.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It the same for multiindex columns

```py
out = df.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name=['Index', 'AssetClass', 'Type'], value_name='Return')
```

NOTE: ensure you read the xlsx file with `header=[0,1,2])` argument to get the multiindex columns

```
print(out)

          Index AssetClass      Type  Return
1-Apr-23  SP500     Equity     Large    3.51
1-Mar-23  SP500     Equity     Large   -2.61
1-Feb-23  SP500     Equity     Large    6.18
1-Jan-23  SP500     Equity     Large   -5.90
1-Apr-23   DJIA     Equity  BlueChip    2.56
1-Mar-23   DJIA     Equity  BlueChip    1.89
1-Feb-23   DJIA     Equity  BlueChip   -4.06
1-Jan-23   DJIA     Equity  BlueChip    2.83
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked like a charm. I read the file as        df = pd.read_excel('filename',header=[0,1,2],index_col=0)